# How to change the session value of php with different events in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
$("#family").dblclick(function(){
 <?php $_SESSION["album_name"] = "family"; ?>
 location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/home_images/";
});
$("#friends").dblclick(function(){
 <?php $_SESSION["album_name"] = "friends"; ?>
 location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/home_images/";
});
$("#work").dblclick(function(){
 <?php $_SESSION["album_name"] = "work"; ?>
 location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/home_images/";
});
$("#others").dblclick(function(){
 <?php $_SESSION["album_name"] = "others"; ?>
 location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/home_images/";
});
```

I want to change the session value with various dblclick events in jquery.
But it is storing the last value ie= "others" even if i dblclick on some other id's.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Learn the difference between server-side and client-side languages. In this case you'll want to use AJAX.

Comment: I suggest learning the difference between javascript and php. Come back once you gathered some basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't output PHP code from JavaScript. With that snippet, your browser will see this:

```
$("#family").dblclick(function(){
 location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/home_images/";
});
$("#friends").dblclick(function(){
 location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/home_images/";
});
$("#work").dblclick(function(){
 location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/home_images/";
});
$("#others").dblclick(function(){
 location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/home_images/";
});
```

While `$_SESSION['album_name']` would contain the last value that you assigned, in this case: 'others'.

Why? Because PHP is interpreted **in your server**, it generates an output (in your case, an HTML document) and sends it in a response.

You could use PHP inside JavaScript, for example, to print values from the server, like this:

```
// Assuming $foo is 'bar', will output var foo = 'bar';
var foo = '<?php echo $_SESSION['foo']; ?>';
```

To do what you are trying to do, you need to make AJAX calls to your server:

```
$("#family").dblclick(function(){
 $.ajax({
   url: 'http://yourdomain.com/album_name.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {albumName: 'family'},
   success: function(response) {
     // this function will be executed when the server responds successfully to the AJAX call
     // response will have whatever you send from the server.
     // In this example: 'ok'
     alert(response);
   }
 });
});
```

Then, in your server:

```
// album_name.php
$whitelist = array('family', 'friends', 'work', 'others'); 

if (isset($_POST['albumName'] && in_array($_POST['albumName'], $whitelist)) 
{
  $_SESSION['album_name'] = $_POST['albumName'];
  echo 'ok';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  ajax for implementing the storing session for every events. Reason for stroung `others` value in session it is last assignment accoring to to that.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can change a `$_SESSION` variable is the server. You therefore need to send a request to a PHP script on the server and have that script update the variable. You can't do it on the client side with JavaScript.

You could add the album_name variable to the query string of the URL you are redirecting to and have index.php look for it and update the session value before executing the rest of the script...

```
...?album_name=family
```

Then somewhere at the start of index.php ...

```
if (isset($_GET['album_name'])) {
    $_SESSION['album_name'] = $_GET['album_name'];
}
```

Make sure this comes after a call to `session_start()` or the `$_SESSION` variable won't exist.